# vendor/store group products by categories - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a `Laravel with MySQL` e-commerce like website, and I need to show all the products under its categories by vendor/store.

I tried the code below, but it is repeating every product, it's not grouping under one category if the products belongs to the same category.

```
Controller:
$products = Product::with('category')->where('store_id',$id)->get();


View:
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->category->name }}
    {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

---

```
Database Structure:

store

id  |  name

---
products - store_id is foreign key of store table and category_id is foreign key of categories table

id | store_id  | category_id | name

---
categories
id | name
```

---

Output I am expecting:

**Category one**

`all products under this category`

**Category two**

`all products under this category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting categories and eager load their products with specific store id

```
$categories = Category::with('products'=> function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('store_id' , $id);
    }])
    ->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('store_id' ,$id);
    })
    ->get();
```

And in view first loop your categories and then related products

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
    @foreach($category->products as $product)
        {{ $product->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes M Khalid, I did it exactly in the view before I saw your updated answer, man thank you very much. The query is exactly correct and that is what I am looking for. Really big help for me.

Comment: oh. I see you've add this line
Category::with('products'=> function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('store_id' , $id);
    }])

Comment: I have a problem. the products under the same category are showing even if the store doesn't have it.

Comment: @KonjeshEsbrading That's not possible as you can see that i have used store filter in where clause as well as in eager loaded production i.e `with()` clause

Comment: you've missed the opening square brackets, it's ok now.

Comment: $categories = Category::with(['products'=> function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('store_id' , $id);
    }]) here it is, thanks M Khalid Junaid